# setuptools - bundle package from framework from relative path

Tags: python, package, setuptools

With a project setup as follows:

```
---------------------
root
   FrameworkPackage1
      __init__.py
     sourcefile1.py

   FrameworkPackage2
      __init__.py
      sourcefile2.py
   apps
       Project
           src
               MyApp
                   __init__.py
                   __main__.py
           setup.py
           README.md
---------------------
```

When I'm creating the setup.py, from what I understand, I use **package_dir** to set the location of these packages.

```
---------------------
    packages=['MyApp', 'FrameworkPackage1', 'FrameworkPackage2'],
    package_dir={'': 'src',
                 'FrameworkPackage1': '../../FrameworkPackage1',
                 'FrameworkPackage2': '../../FrameworkPackage2'}
---------------------
```

So this correctly builds a package with all the required files.  However, when I try to install, it fails, and if I just try to untar/gz the package file it puts FrameworkPackage1/2 in the "../../.." dir from where the unzip happens.

Ideally I'd like the package to work as follows and install from pip so I could run the following:

```
import MyApp as ma
import FrameworkPackage1 as fp1
import FrameworkPackage2 as fp2

print(ma.Function())
print(fp1.OtherFunction())
print(fp2.OtherFunction())
```

Is there a way to set the frameworks to be found in "../../../" but install into the root of the distribution?

Comment: See if this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/17179022/4619142, you might be doing something slightly wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `'FrameworkPackage1': '../../FrameworkPackage1'`? I mean `../../../` takes you to the parent directory of `root`. Or is there something wrong with the display of your directory layout?

Comment: Yes!  Sorry.. that's an error in my example.  I will edit + update now

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as @a_guest suggested, shouldn't the `package_dir` look like this?

```
packages=['MyApp', 'FrameworkPackage1', 'FrameworkPackage2'],
package_dir={'': 'src',
             'FrameworkPackage1': '../../FrameworkPackage1',
             'FrameworkPackage2': '../../FrameworkPackage2'}
```

Alternatively, you could try adding a `__init__.py` to the `root` folder so that it is recognized as a python folder (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155804/confused-about-the-package-dir-and-packages-settings-in-setup-py/17179022))

Secondly, instead of using this bundled structure for your package, you could either:

- **If the Framework packages are used elsewhere**: Treat each package separately. This would allow you to evolve them separately, and add them to your `MyApp` by simply including them in the `requirements.txt` (or equivalents). A con of this is that each one would have its own setup.py, but this is a [much better packaging practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598299/when-is-it-not-appropriate-to-bundle-dependencies-with-an-application).
- **If the Framework packages are not used elsewhere (or you just want your local copy)**: Switch to a project setup with the `setup.py` directly in the main folder (    `package_dir={'': 'src', 'FrameworkPackage1': 'src', 'FrameworkPackage2': 'src'}`, with a structure looking like:

```
---------------------
...
       Project
           src
               MyApp
                   __init__.py
                   __main__.py
               FrameworkPackage1
                   __init__.py
                   sourcefile1.py
               FrameworkPackage2
                   __init__.py
                   sourcefile2.py
           setup.py
           README.md
---------------------
```